# Difference between custom layout and flow layout in UICollectionView in Objective-C

Tags: ios, xcode, uicollectionview

What is the difference between custom layout and flow layout in `UICollectionView` in Objective-C :-

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2):

The difference depends on what custom layout you use. There may be cases, when the standard flow layout is not exactly what you want, for example if your items have variable sizes and you want the item spacing to be always the same. The standard flow layout will leave the gaps where it can't align items with different sizes.

For such cases you may want to use a custom layout, for example [CHTCollectionViewWaterfallLayout](https://github.com/chiahsien/CHTCollectionViewWaterfallLayout). I'm mentioning this one specifically, because it solves the gaps problem I described earlier. Now, if you initialize your collection view from xib you can just change the layout to custom and change the class of the layout to whatever you need and you are set.

Comment: I have a CollectionViewHeader which i created using storyboard and i am displaying labels programmatically in viewForSupplementaryElementOfKind but i want to display 3 labels horizontally according to the size of words a label has. For that what i have to do ?(and for this reason i was asking the difference between custom and flow layout)

Comment: I'd suggest creating a new question for this, and don't forget to show the code.

Answer (score 1):

A flow layout is `UICollectionViewFlowLayout`. A custom layout is **subclass** of `UICollectionViewLayout`.`UICollectionViewFlowLayout` has its default implementation while `UICollectionViewLayout` should be customized.